# Moving Image in a table

Tags: html

```
<td width="570">
   <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="530">
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td rowspan="7" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="85"><img src="img here!"></td>
                        <td rowspan="7" height="100%" width="20">
                           <table width="20">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:10px;font-size:1px;" colspan="1" nowrap="" height="10" valign="top" width="425"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width="425">
                           <h3 style="color: #172E4D; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:19px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"> How to sell a cafe, sandwich bar, fish and chip shop... </h3>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:15px;font-size:1px;" colspan="1" nowrap="" height="15" valign="top" width="425"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width="425"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="color: #666666; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:17px; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" width="100%">Well, not just selling a cafe, selling any food or drink related business can be tough, with over 8,000 other food and drink related businesses actively trying to sell you need the right advice.</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:10px;font-size:1px;" colspan="1" nowrap="" height="10" valign="top" width="425"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="425">
                           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tbody> </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
```

Hi i am looking to move the image to the right and the text to the left. I have been trying to do it for hours but just cant seem to get it right, please help!

Comment: What image?  What text?  What specifically have you done to try to solve the issue?

Comment: hello i have added a screen shot to this text of how it looks like but i want to change the image to the right and the text to the left. I have been looking on google for hours on how to do this and just cannot get it right if i get the picture right the text doesnt work. https://i.gyazo.com/c7250eab82e609d9d972b33ff6684a5f.png

Answer (score 2):

Try this you had a ton of unneccessary table rows and columns. the image is now spanning 2 rows and is on the right.

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="width:570px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="425px">
                <h3 style="color: #172E4D; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:19px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"> How to sell a cafe, sandwich bar, fish and chip shop... </h3></td>
            <td rowspan="7" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="85">
                <img src="img here!">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:17px; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" width="100%">Well, not just selling a cafe, selling any food or drink related business can be tough, with over 8,000 other food and drink related businesses actively trying to sell you need the right advice.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has fixed the problem, sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: no problem! i figured i could help out in a minute or two.

Comment: Struggling to find out how to mark my question as answered

Comment: a quick explanation: within your table row <tr> you have your table cells <td> the first table cell would be the first one after your <tr> tag. you placed your image in the first one and your comments in the second one several <tr> down. Just as a quick tip: use the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Might i suggest playing with the basics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table)